# Period DataType Support in HIVE to TERDATA Export

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

Whenver we are trying to export to period datatype column in Terdata from HIVE column(e.g 2014/02/01,2015/01/01) using sqoop, it fails the job. Does anybody know if period datatype is supported in sqoop exports.

Comment: Are you using a Teradata connector for Hortonworks or Cloudera?

Answer (score 0):

Hortonwork's connector for Teradata does support PERIOD data types. However, the Cloudera connector for Teradata does not support PERDIO data types currently.